# Discord.js / JS What is the difference here

Tags: javascript, discord.js

What is the difference between a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
let collection = new Map()
```

And a discord.js [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection):

```
let collection = new Discord.Collection()
```

Or both are basically the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described in Discord's [docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html):

> Discord.js comes with this utility class known as Collection. It extends JavaScript's native Map class, so it has all the features of Map and more!

> In essence, Map allow for an association between unique keys and their values, but lack an iterative interface. For example, how can you transform every value or filter the entries in a Map easily? This is the point of the Collection class!

Discord collections are Maps that also have:

- Certain array prototype methods like `.find`, `.filter`, `.every`
- `.array()` (converts the collection to an array)
- Various other utility methods like `.random()` (gives a random value), `.first()` (gives the first value), `.last()` (gives the last value), `.sweep` (removes all values from the collection that fail the callback). See the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html) for details.

Comment: So in simple words, it is javascript map but better?

Comment: @ImagineGamingPlay yes.